# Examine whether the identity map is continuous or NOT.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Consider the space $C[0,1]$. Consider the following metrics

$$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt.$$

$$d_2(f,g)=\left(\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}.$$

$$d_3(f,g)=\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|f(t)-g(t)|.$$

Then which are correct ?

(a) $id:(X,d_2)\to (X,d_1)$ is continuous.

(b) $id:(X,d_1)\to (X,d_3)$ is continuous.

(c) $id:(X,d_3)\to (X,d_2)$ is continuous.

I only know that for a Topological space $id:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ is continuous if $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$.

Can we apply this for this problem ?
Or any other technique to test the continuity ?

**Update:**

According to   Fardad Pouran's comment ,

$$d_2(f,g)=\left(\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}$$

$$\le \left(\int_0^1\left(\sup_{0\le t \le 1} |f(t)-g(t)|\right)^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}$$

$$=\left(\int_0^1\left( d_3(f,g)\right)^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}$$

$$=d_3(f,g).$$

So,(c) is **TRUE**.

Again,$$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt$$

$$\le \int_0^1\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt=d_3(f,g).$$

So, (b) is **FALSE**.

Again, $$d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|\,dt$$

$$\le \left(\int_0^1|f(t)-g(t)|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2}=d_3(f,g)$$ , using Cauchy-Schwarz inequlity.

So, (a) is **TRUE**.

Check whether I am right or wrong ?

Comment: It seems you should find constants, say $C_{ij}$, such that :
$$d_i(f,g)\leq C_{ij}d_j(f,g)$$
Then you've proved that identity functions are even *Lipschitz*

Comment: Hints: Because each metric comes from a norm, you may as well assume $g = 0$. Now as yourself questions such as, "If $\int |f_{n}| \to 0$, does it follow that $\sup |f_{n}| \to 0$?

Comment: @  Fardad Pouran): Please check my thoughts about my question in UPDATE....

Comment: You're right with respect to a) and c) including the proofs. While you are correct with your answer to b), the inequality $d_1(f,g) \leqslant d_3(f,g)$ does not imply that the identity is not continuous from the $d_1$-endowed space to the $d_3$-endowed. Consider $d_4(f,g) = 2\cdot d_1(f,g)$ to see that.

Comment: Well...We know that, " A Topological space $id:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ is continuous if $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$." Again every Topological space is a metric space. So how this result related in metric space?...@ Daniel Fischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Daniel Fisher, we cannot conclude that b) is false by the argument given. Instead consider the functions :  $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$.Then $lim_{n\to\infty}||x^n-0||=0$  on $(X,d_1)$ whereas  $lim_{n\to\infty}||x^n-0||=1$ on $(X,d_3)$ ( where the norm is induced by the metric ).

Comment: How $x^n$ is identity function ?

Comment: $x^n$ is not the identity map. $({x^n})$ are elements of $(C[0,1],d_1)$ as well as $(C[0,1],d_3)$.

Comment: Ok.Without creating example , is it possible to check using any theorem that the identity function in **NOT** continuous ? Because for these type of problems in examination hall creating example is very difficult ...

Comment: That's a very good question. I also have the same doubt. will try to find if there is any other way out.

Comment: Ok. I will also try..If you find out then please suggest me here.